# FIDO client access to BLE Authenticator

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, authenticator, fido

FIDO client stack supports Bluetooth attestation and assertion by first locating a paired authenticator device with a FIDO GATT and then attempting to connect to that device using it’s paired address. Both Android and iOS BLE stacks incorporate Resolvable Private Address methods; meaning on each new advertisement from an authenticator App on the device a new device address is assigned by the stack. During device discovery the new device address is mapped by the stack to the original paired address using IRK exchanged at time of pairing. The FIDO client stack on Chrome (and others) fails to find the App on Android or iOS and always times out. But, if in another tab I run device discovery, for example by using navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice (), to find the Android or iOS App and then run the same FIDO request, all is good. This seems to suggest the FIDO stack in skips device discovery. Has anyone encountered this and if so, how to resolve it?